# How can I extract AC-3 or DTS or any other audio streaming from a bulk collection of MP4 videos simultaniously with FFmpeg?

Tags: sound

I want to just extract audio files without encoding or decoding for many MP4 videos simultaneously using the [FFmpeg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg) decoder.
What would the git bash be for my requirement?

Comment: try your luck on stackoverflow.

Comment: What do you mean by *"git bash"*? *"[Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633)"*? Something on [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub)? Something else? (Please respond by [editing your question](https://sound.stackexchange.com/posts/46536/edit), not here in comments (as appropriate). Thanks in advance.)

Comment: This translates to "please write some code for me for free".